# Can't kill process with Task Manager or taskkill

Tags: windows, process, task-manager, kill

There are some processes wich I start, they freeze (don't even get to the GUI), and then I'm unable to kill them. These are usually programs I wrote or compiled.

When I try to kill them via Task Manager, End Process button doesn't do anything, although neither does it throw some error, it acts as if everything was OK, but doesn't kill the process.

I tried to kill them from command prompt, this is the result:

```
C:\Users\icguy>tasklist | findstr SubShifter.exe
SubShifter.exe                6280 Console                    1        120 K
SubShifter.exe                7000 Console                    1        120 K
SubShifter.exe                5276 Console                    1        128 K

C:\Users\icguy>taskkill /im subshifter.exe /F
SUCCESS: The process "SubShifter.exe" with PID 6280 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "SubShifter.exe" with PID 7000 has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process "SubShifter.exe" with PID 5276 has been terminated.

C:\Users\icguy>tasklist | findstr SubShifter.exe
SubShifter.exe                6280 Console                    1        120 K
SubShifter.exe                7000 Console                    1        120 K
SubShifter.exe                5276 Console                    1        128 K
```

I'm not feeling like rebooting everytime I encounter this problem. Solution, anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just after posting this, I've found a solution to the problem. I disabled Avast (my antivirus for anyone not knowing), and the processes run just fine.

Comment: Hmm. I have to say this antivirus detects a lot of false positives for me

Comment: I know, right? And the funny thing is that it worked just fine for years.